# No funciona reproducir con MediaPlayer en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, audio, mediaplayer

Estoy teniendo serios dolores de cabeza para reproducir audio en Android Studio. Tengo una aplicación a parte más compleja en la que lo intento y a la hora de reproducir el audio no se escucha nada, pero no salta ningún error en consola.

Entonces he probado a hacer una pequeña aplicación simple en la que solo se grabe y reproduzca audio (código abajo) y tengo el mismo problema. No se reproduce nada aún después de grabar y sin recibir ningún error por consola.

Tengo los dos permisos Write External y Record audio en el Manifest y el volumen del ordenador activado. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaRecorder grabacion;
    String outputFile;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1000);
        }
        grabacion = new MediaRecorder();
    }

    public void Grabar(View view) {
        outputFile= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/grabacion.3gp";
        grabacion.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        grabacion.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        grabacion.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        grabacion.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        try {
            grabacion.prepare();
            grabacion.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Grabando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void Detener(View view) {
        if(grabacion!=null) {
            grabacion.stop();
            grabacion.release();
            grabacion = null;
        }
    }

    public void Escuchar(View view) {
        MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            m.setDataSource(outputFile);
            Log.d("primerTry", outputFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("error", e.toString());

        }
        try {
            m.prepare();
            Log.d("segundoTry", outputFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("error2", e.toString());


        }
        m.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Que error se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: Obviando el resto del texto en consola (por los procesos al ejecutar el emulador), lo que obtengo en consola al pulsar Grabar, Detener y Escuchar de manera consecutiva es lo siguiente: `D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde7852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xde7836b0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde7852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xde7836b0)
W/MediaRecorder: mediarecorder went away with unhandled events
D/primerTry: /storage/emulated/0/grabacion.3gp
D/segundoTry: /storage/emulated/0/grabacion.3gp`